# Isn't a homeomorphism between an open interval and $\mathbb{R}$ a contradiction?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X = (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$. Define $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = \tan(x), \, \forall x \in X$. It can be shown that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

We have that $X$ is an open set. $\mathbb{R}$ is open and closed. By the homeomorphism, $X$ should be open, once $\mathbb{R}$ is open; but also closed since $\mathbb{R}$ is closed.

However, $X$ is not closed.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: $X$ is closed in its subspace topology.

Comment: Isn't every set open in its own subspace topology (I mean, given a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, we have $A \cap \mathbb{R} = A$, therefore $A$ is open). Furthermore, I can't see how this answer my question...

Comment: Oh, I think I have read it wrong, I thought you said "X is open...". Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing you are missing is that a homeomorphism is a morphism of spaces and not sets of a space. When you are considering the interval as the origin of the homeomorphism, you are really comparing a topology on $\mathbb{R}$, and a topology on the interval (the relative topology on the interval). As the interval is the whole set of that topological space, it is, indeed, closed, even though it may not be closed as a subset of the reals

Comment: I completely understand. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: So when we are considering homeomorphisms between sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, we are not really considering them as sets, but we are considering them as the sets in topological spaces together with the subspace topology induced by $\mathbb{R}^{n}$...

Comment: To argue that two sets $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic we usually search for topological invariants that differ between these two sets. But we are usually viewing them as subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. By my comment above we should look at them as topological spaces by themselves. Is there a theorem that states something like "If $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ have some topological property (viewed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then $(X, \tau)$, where $\tau$ is the subspace topology induced by $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ also have this property" ?

Comment: For example, it's easy to prove that if $X$ is a disconnected set (viewed as a  $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ subset), then X with the subspace topology is also disconnected. As a proof, if $X = A \cup B$, where $A,B$ are disjoints open sets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ then $X \cap A$ is an open set of $X$ and $X\cap A = A$. Also $X \cap B = B$ is also an open subset of $X$ then $X = A \cup B$, $A,B$ now as disjoints open sets of $X$. By this we conclude $(X, \tau)$ is disconnected.

Comment: That's another really nice question. Sadly, I think the answer is that it depends. A lot. Many of the properties we often use as invariants of homeomorphism (n-homotopy groups, several separation axioms, etc) need not be preserved for subspaces. There are several properties, however that display this "inheritance" behaviour. You have proven it for being disconnected, and also being Hausdorff is inheritable, which is a very important property, although stronger properties need not be, for example, being a $T_4$ space

Comment: Arguments that are parallel for several properties can be reused to prove that several are inheritable in one go, but there are examples of topological properties that do not display this behaviour, and as far as I know, there is no general result for determining when this happens

Comment: So in general, we can not look up for topological invariants of subspaces looking at them just from the point of view of the ambient space. But we have to "get in the subspace" to seek for the more peculiar ones. I see. Thank you very much!! That clarifies a lot. By the way, I was also able to prove that compactness has this "inheritance" behaviour, as you said.

Comment: Also, some cool results relate not only to this fact, but also to the fact that it even depends on the subspace you are looking at. For example, a subspace of a $T_4$ space need not be $T_4$, but if the subspace is closed as a subset of the larger space then it is. Topological properties are weird sometimes, but these questions are really nice, I hope you enjoy learning and thinking about this stuff